# Creepy log line in Google Play Integrity API

Tags: google-play-integrity-api

I'm researching the Play Integrity API as a first step of migration from SafetyNet.
There is one log line that repeats in every flow, either successful or not:

```
PlayCore I  UID: [10547]  PID: [7783] IntegrityService : linkToDeath
```

Any idea what does it mean? I don't want to die yet, lol.
On a serious note: is someone experiences this ?